# Publishing/Sending in Mediator ConsumeContext scope using MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit, mediator

In my ASP.NET core controller, I send a command using IMediator.Send

```
await mediator.Send(new SubmitOrder());
```

The consumer of the SubmitOrder looks like this

```
public class SubmitOrderConsumer : IConsumer<SubmitOrder>
{
    public async Task Consume( ConsumeContext<SubmitOrder> context )
    {
        var sendEndpoint = await context.GetSendEndpoint( new Uri( "rabbitmq://localhost/notification-service" ) );
        await sendEndpoint.Send( new NotifyOrderSubmitted() );
    }
}
```

Sending a message to a transport results in a error message

`MassTransit.MessageNotConsumedException: 'loopback://localhost/mediator => The message was not consumed'`

Publishing a doest add a message on to RabbitMQ

Is there a way to do this with the `ConsumeContext` rather than injecting `IBusControl` or `IBus` as i would like to keep the context of the message thread

Answer (score 1):

When consuming messages within Mediator, the interfaces are all mediator-related. To *jump the tracks* from mediator to the bus, you'd need to reference the bus (via `IBus`) via dependency injection to the consumer.

Comment: This is was I suspected, this is a shame. My concern is other devs in my team would just default to using the IBus to send messages even when in a bus related consumer, as it will get hard to trace back to the original interface that triggered the consumer. Do you have a suggestions on this? Sorry I’m new to MT

Comment: Well, my first recommendation would be to avoid using mediator altogether if you're using a bus. I don't understand why people try to over-obfuscate behavior by introducing so many different abstractions.

Comment: Thanks is Chris, would the best way to fire off the consumer straight from the controller?

Comment: No, it would be best to publish the `SubmitOrder` message from the controller, and let the consumer run via RabbitMQ – which would then publish the `OrderSubmitted` notification. Very similar to what I do in [ForkJoint](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ForkJoint/blob/master/src/ForkJoint.Api/Controllers/OrderController.cs#L41).